# Left inset padding on UISearchBar text field (iOS7) cause text to cover clear button

Tags: ios7, uitextfield, uisearchbar

I have a UISearchBar with a *searchTextPositionAdjustment* which is causing the text to overlay and display on top of the (x) clear button that appears on the right side of the SearchBar.

I have tried quite a few suggestions from other answers including enumerating the UISearchBar subviews to locate the UITextField and then changing it's frame / bounds & adding a rightView, but currently haven't found a solution.

If I decrease the adjustment it will come to a point where it doesn't cover this clear button and it's almost as if the UITextField within the UISearchBar is being shifted but not shrinking in width to keep equal space on the RH edge. However I can't seem to find a way to set a right inset as well, unless I'm missing something obvious.

Comment: Please __add code__, and take a __[tour]__.

Comment: Not sure what code I could add as it's mainly laid out in IB, unless you want me to list all that I've tried? I did add a picture of the issue but don't have enough points to submit.

Comment: Please upload it to an image hosting service like imgur and give a link down in the comments. I will embed it for you.

Comment: Did you make this work ?